# SQL Server Error in MS Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Some users are getting an error message when trying to attach a file to a case but it's not very helpful. It just says SQL Server Error. A SQL Server error occurred.

Is there a recommended place to go to find more information on why an error happened? The user has a "Download Log File" button their screenshot of the error but it is greyed out. I assume someone with higher permissions would be able to download this log file?

I have read about Stunnware as a good tool for reading logs? Is this the best one to use?

Comment: Is your question about best practice for reading logs or for a possible solution of your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach that doesn't require [a SQL Server trace](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006(v=sql.105).aspx) is to use the Dynamics CRM 'trace logging' feature that you can enable for on-premises servers.

Here are details on trace logging and how to set it up:

- [Monitor and troubleshoot Microsoft Dynamics 365](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699694.aspx)
- [How to enable tracing in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/907490/how-to-enable-tracing-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm)

If you set it up once, with all default settings only, you will get a log entry for generic SQL errors that includes the actual message SQL Server threw. It's not as detailed as a SQL Server SQL trace (e.g. you can't look at the query that is failing) but it gives you a more specific error message. We have trace logging enabled for all our Dynamics CRM development machines and it can speed up this kind of debugging nicely.

Answer (score 3):

More than likely, the CRM log will just have the same error like "Generic SQL Error" or "SQL Server error."  We have had success starting a trace on the SQL Server and then execute the action that is causing the error. The trace will usually give you much more information about the actual error.